# Styling Menu Mini panels

Tags: routes, javascript

I'm having an issue with styling my menu mini panel hover.

Here's the site with the megamenu I'm working on:
http://drupal.scienceworld.ca

As I'm rather new to JS, I was wondering what the best way to center the foldout menu in the browser would be?

Answer (score -1):

This isn't exactly a Drupal question but if you add the following to your CSS this will accomplish I think what you want.

```
div.qtip {
  top: 170px !important;
  left: 370px !important;
}
```

Adjust the values to suite your needs.

Edit: You may want to qualify that block of CSS further by prepending with it's wrapper or something, just to give it context and not break these qtip menus in other places

Comment: Alexander, thank you, but I had thought of that solution. I found that as the browser window changes in size, using pixels doesn't seem to be the best solution. But I appreciate your reply!